# Looking for an active USB 3.2 Gen 1 (or 2) hub with at least 10 ports, half of which are USB-A and USB-C respectively

Tags: usb, hub, usb-c

I am looking for *an **active*** USB 3.2 Gen 1 -- or preferably Gen 2 -- hub which comes with at least **ten** usable **ports**, half of which should be USB-C sockets and the other half of which should be USB-A sockets.

I would prefer for the uplink to be USB-C based. From my cursory research on the topic this may even be a technical requirement, but I wasn't a 100% clear when I finished researching this topic.

No need for the various "standards" for quick charging.

PS: to my knowledge, I do have two USB-C uplink ports built into my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A larger USB hub will always contain multiple USB hub ICs daisy chained inside so getting a single device is not necessarily advantageous. But, searching, say, Newegg for usb 3.2 gen 2 hub finds a ton of of devices these days, that's not a problem any more.

The problem is *bandwidth*. 10 ports at 10 gigabits would consume 100 gigabits and there's absolutely no way currently to get this much bandwidth. The most bandwidth you can potentially get out of a laptop is utilizing four PCIe 4.0 lanes (like from an M.2 socket utilizing a OCuLink riser with a redriver). Actually. Lenovo's new ThinkBook 14+ 2024 will feature OCuLink , the GPD Win Max 2 also has it. That's 64Gbps. The [One Dock](https://www.1-dock.com/en-us/#/) can convert that to a PCIe slot. Alas, AFAIK there no USB root hub connecting over PCIe 4.0 so this avenue while promising currently doesn't go far.

Using more traditional interfaces, the best we can do is USB4. The ADT-Link UT3G is utilizing the ASMedia ASM2464PD and can nearly provide as much bandwidth as PCIe 3.0 x4 possibly can, benchmarks showed around 30Gbps. You can add a dual ASM3142 card like the SI-PEX20233. Each ASM3142 provides two 10gbps ports from two PCIe 3.0 lanes -- it's slightly oversubscribed but not terribly.